# How do I replace a link between <a></a> and keep the link from href unchanged?

Tags: php, regex

How do I replace a link between  and keep the link from href unchanged?

This is my code:

```
$str="Lorem Ipsum.<a href='https://test.be/assets/kcfinder/upload/files/certificat_auto.pdf'>https://test.be/assets/kcfinder/upload/files/certificat_auto.pdf</a>Lorem Ipsum ";

$pattern = '/>https:\/\/test.be\/assets\/kcfinder\/upload\/files\/.*\./';
$replacement = '>${1}';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

This is the output:

```
Lorem Ipsum.<a href='https://test.be/assets/kcfinder/upload/files/certificat_auto.pdf'>pdf</a>Lorem Ipsum
```

I need the output to be :

```
Lorem Ipsum.<a href='https://test.be/assets/kcfinder/upload/files/certificat_auto.pdf'>certificat_auto.pdf</a>Lorem Ipsum
```

I'm doing something wrong with the replacement, the pattern matches

Comment: With `$3`, you are referencing Group 3, and you have none in your regex.

Comment: Do you *need* to use regexp here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Use preg match to check if your regex pattern is even working at all see regex101.com for a good online tester and debugger

Answer (score 0):

You may get some idea from this.

```
(?<=>)https:\/\/test.be\/assets\/kcfinder\/upload\/files\/[\w\.]*
```

https://rubular.com/r/b46dQ9G27C4A3A